# Differentiable orthogonal vector

Tags: math, 3d

Does anybody know a simple and differentiable function that converts a 3D vector `u = (x, y, z)` to another vector that is orthogonal to `u`.

To be more precise, I am looking for three differentiable functions `{f, g, h}` such that the vector `u = (x, y, z)` is orthogonal to `v = (f(x,y,z), g(x,y,z), h(x,y,z))` and `v` is zero only if `u` is zero.

The functions `{f, g, h}` should be as simple as possible. I prefer them linear, but I think no such linear functions exist. Low degree polynomials are also good.

P.S. I found such functions, but they are not polynomials. For example:

```
f(x, y, z) = y*(exp(x) + 3) - z*(exp(x) + 2)
g(x, y, z) = z*(exp(x) + 1) - x*(exp(x) + 3)
h(x, y, z) = x*(exp(x) + 2) - y*(exp(x) + 1)
```

It's simply the cross product of (x,y,z) with (exp(x)+1, exp(x)+2, exp(x)+3). It satisfies all requirements except for being polynomials. But they are quite simple.

Comment: Your example functions won't work if (x, y, z) is proportional to (exp(x)+1, exp(x)+2, exp(x)+3) (that is, y = x*(exp(x)+2)/(exp(x)+1), z = x*(exp(x)+3)/(exp(x)+1)), as the dot product is zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No such a continuous function can exist. It's a consequence of the ["hairy ball"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) theorem that states that there can be no continuous never-vanishing tangent field defined over a sphere (if you could get `F(v)` non-zero, continuous and always orthogonal to `v` then `v-F(v)` could be used to easily define a continuous never-vanishing tangent field over a sphere).

On the other hand if the function doesn't need to be continuous then the problem is easy. What I normally do is to pick what is the bigger between Y and Z component of `v` (in absolute value) and then computing the cross product between `v` and `(0, 1, 0)` if Z component is bigger or `(0, 0, 1)` if Y component is bigger. This avoids the singularity.

Answer (score 1):

`v = (y - z, z - x, x - y)`

This seems to match all your criteria, except for being non-zero for non-zero `u`. For example, `u = (1, 1, 1)` blows it up. I suspect you may be right that there is no linear solution.